# How to move javascript yml string to database the to ruby array

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, yaml

I have a javascript function that can create either a yaml string.  I then put that yaml string into a hidden_field in my form so that when the form is submitted the string is loaded into a database column.  My problem is then cleanly reading the column and putting the yml representation a ruby array of hashes.  Part of what I have to deal with is that the \r\n are stored as text in the db column.  Yes I played with serializing the column but since the hidden_field is text...

I can't find a clean way to do this. My yaml string looks roughly like this:

```
chapter:
  title: foo
    rating: awful
    words: 1000
  title: bar
    rating: fun
    words: 3
```

Comment: It's a bad idea to accept arbitrary YAML from the client. Might want to JSON encode that and convert on the server-side instead.

Comment: I understand and agree.  I have vastly simplified what is really going on here to focus on my question.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good architecture. Your YAML represents an object and should be stored as an object with attributes. Storing serialized data (yes YAML counts as serialized) is a bad practice.

Ruby deals with YAML easily

If you are on ruby 1.8.X, you'll need the psych gem

http://rubygems.org/gems/psych

Example:

```
require 'rubygems' #necessary only for 1.8.X
require 'yaml'

##Load a YAML string into a ruby Hash
ruby_hash = YAML.load(my_yaml_string)

##Get YAML string from ruby Hash
yaml_string = YAML.dump(ruby_hash)
```